# Como excluir a última linha de um arquivo texto na linguagem C

Tags: c, c++, arquivo, padrão-de-texto

Galera, estou com uma dúvida de como deveria excluir a ultima linha de um arquivo usando a linguagem C. Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor.

Abaixo, segue meu código.

```
int quantidadeDeUsuarios = 0;
Usuario *_usuario;



void sair() {
    free(_usuario);
}

void removerUltimoNumero() {

    FILE *arquivo;

    char *linha = (char *) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
    char *buffer = (char *) malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
    char *ponteiro;

    memset(buffer, 0, 1000 * sizeof(char));
    ponteiro = buffer;

    arquivo = fopen("usuarios", "r");

    if(arquivo == NULL) {
        cout << "Erro na abertura do arquivo" << endl;
        return;
    }

    while(!feof(arquivo)) {

        fgets(linha, 256, arquivo);

        if(sizeof(linha) == true) {
            strcpy(ponteiro, linha);
            ponteiro += strlen(linha);
        }
    }

    fclose(arquivo);
    rescreveArquivo(arquivo, buffer);
    free(linha);
    free(buffer);
}

void rescreveArquivo(FILE *arquivo, const char *buffer) {
    arquivo = fopen("usuarios", "w");
    fprintf(arquivo, "%s", buffer);
    fclose(arquivo);
}

void numeroDeUsuariosCadastrados() {
    cout << "Número de usuários cadastrados: " << contadorDeLinhasDeUmArquivo() << endl;
}

int contadorDeLinhasDeUmArquivo() {

    FILE *arquivo;
    int numeroDeLinhas = 0;

    arquivo = fopen("usuarios", "r");

    if(arquivo == NULL) {
        cout << "Erro na abertura do arquivo" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    while(EOF != (scanf("%*[^\n]") && scanf("%*c"))) {
        ++numeroDeLinhas;
    }

    return numeroDeLinhas;
}

void listarUsuarios() {

    char *saida = (char *) malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
    char espaco = ' ';

    FILE *arquivo = fopen("usuarios", "r");

    if(arquivo == NULL) {
        cout << "Erro na Abertura do arquivo" << endl;
        return;
    }

    cout << "=========================================================================================================================================================" << endl;
    printf("| Nome %-25c | RG %-27c | CPF %-26c | Endereço %-41c |\n", espaco, espaco, espaco, espaco);
    cout << "=========================================================================================================================================================" << endl;

    for (int i = 1; fgets(saida, sizeof(saida), arquivo) != NULL; ++i) {
        printf("%s", saida);
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    fclose(arquivo);

}

void cadastrarUsuario() {

    Usuario *usuario;

    usuario = _usuario;

    if(quantidadeDeUsuarios > 0) usuario = (Usuario *) realloc(usuario, quantidadeDeUsuarios * sizeof(Usuario));
    else usuario = (Usuario *) malloc(sizeof(Usuario));

    if(!usuario) {
        cout << "Exaustão de memória!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    __fpurge(stdin);
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Digite seu nome: ";
    cin.getline(usuario[quantidadeDeUsuarios].nome, 100);

    __fpurge(stdin);
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Digite seu RG: ";
    cin.getline(usuario[quantidadeDeUsuarios].rg, 9);

    __fpurge(stdin);
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Digite seu CPF: ";
    cin.getline(usuario[quantidadeDeUsuarios].cpf, 11);

    __fpurge(stdin);
    cin.clear();
    cout << "Digite seu Endereço: ";
    cin.getline(usuario[quantidadeDeUsuarios].endereco, 100);

    _usuario = usuario;

    insereUsuario(_usuario);

    quantidadeDeUsuarios++;

}

void insereUsuario(Usuario *pUsuario) {

    FILE * arquivo;

    if((arquivo = fopen("usuarios", "a+")) == NULL) {
        cout << "Erro ao criar o arquivo";
    }

    fprintf(arquivo, "| %-30s | %-30s | %-30s | %-50s |\n",
            pUsuario->nome,
            pUsuario->rg,
            pUsuario->cpf,
            pUsuario->endereco
    );

    fclose(arquivo);

}
```

Comment: Tem tanta coisa errada ou ruim nesse código que eu não sei por onde começar (nem olhei além do que está na janela). Se vai decidir se vai fazer em C ou C++? Consegue garantir que a linha tem 256 caracteres? Acho que não, né? Se colocar o código todo talvez eu consiga fazer alguma coisa, mas não prometo porque não tenho compilador C aqui pra testar.

Comment: https://github.com/codenome/Lista0-EstruturaDeDados/tree/master/Exericicio%207%20(FALTA%20FUN%C3%87%C3%83O%20DE%20EXCLUIR)/usuariosArquivos
Este é o link do projeto!

https://github.com/codenome/Lista0-EstruturaDeDados/blob/master/Exericicio%207%20(FALTA%20FUN%C3%87%C3%83O%20DE%20EXCLUIR)/usuariosArquivos/usuario.cpp
Este acima é a do código!

Comment: Outra coisa... estou fazendo em C mesmo... maisa frente o professor vai usar C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema levando os dados de um arquivo texto para uma alocação dinâmica. Em seguida, tratei o ponteiro da locação escrevendo os dados no mesmo arquivo.

```
void removerUltimoUsuario() {

FILE *arquivo = fopen("usuarios.csv", "r");

if(arquivo == NULL) {
    cout << "Erro ao criar o arquivo" << endl;
}

Usuario *usuarios = (Usuario *) malloc(numeroDeUsuarios() * sizeof(Usuario));

char linha[500];
int i = 0;
for(; fgets(linha, 500, arquivo); i++) {
    linha[strlen(linha) - 1] = '\0';
    sscanf(linha, "%[^;];%[^;];%[^;];%[^;];",
           usuarios[i].nome,
           usuarios[i].rg,
           usuarios[i].cpf,
           usuarios[i].endereco
    );
}
cout << "N: " << i << endl;
fclose(arquivo);
insereUsuarios(usuarios, i);
free(usuarios);

cout << "Usuário removido com sucesso!" << endl;
}




void insereUsuarios(Usuario *pUsuario, int numUsuarios) {

FILE * arquivo;

if((arquivo = fopen("usuarios.csv", "w")) == NULL) {
    cout << "Erro ao criar o arquivo";
}

cout << "N: " << numUsuarios << endl;

for(int i = 0; i < (numUsuarios-1); i++) {
    fprintf(arquivo, "%s;%s;%s;%s\n",
            pUsuario[i].nome,
            pUsuario[i].rg,
            pUsuario[i].cpf,
            pUsuario[i].endereco
    );
}

fclose(arquivo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem uma forma bem simples utilizando a sua função que já conta a quantidade de linhas do arquivo. Mas antes, quero deixar claro que não revisei e nem testei seu código. Apenas vou deixar uma solução teórica que cabe a você implementar. **Vamos lá**.

1. Primeiramente crie um arquivo de saída.
2. Agora tendo em mãos o arquivo de saída criado e a quantidade de linhas do arquivo original, copie linha por linha do arquivo original para o de saída.
3. Ao chegar na última linha(que você quer excluir) é só ignorar, ou seja, não copie ela para o arquivo de saída.
4. Você tem agora 2 arquivos, o original e o de saída. Renomeie ou exclua o arquivo original e mantenha o arquivo de saída como sendo o "novo original".

Creio que esta solução não seja a mais recomendada. Mas até onde li o teu código, esta é a melhor forma de causar menos impacto na sua implementação.

**OBS: Não se esqueça de tratar todos os erros durante este processo. Isso vai garantir que o seu arquivo de saída esteja íntegro da forma como você esperava.**

Comment: Obrigado Carlos Givisiez!
Vou executar este procedimento!

Comment: Por nada @ThiagoCunha , comente quando você tiver testado! Aguardo.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema! Vou deixar nos comentários abaixo.